# Jquery Ajax Call, doesn't call Success or Error

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I am using Jquery Ajax to call a service to update a value.

```
function ChangePurpose(Vid, PurId) {
    var Success = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CHService.asmx/SavePurpose",
        dataType: "text",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Vid: Vid, PurpId: PurId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            Success = true;//doesn't go here
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Success = false;//doesn't go here
        }

    });
    //done after here
    return Success;
}
```

and Service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SavePurpose(int Vid, int PurpId)
{
    try 
    {
        CHData.UpdatePurpose(Vid, PurpId);
        //List<IDName> abc = new List<IDName>();
        //abc.Add(new IDName { Name=1, value="Success" });
        return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

the service is being called Successfully from the AJAX. **Value is also being Changed.** But after the Service, **success:** or **error:** functions are **not being called**, in this case success should have been called but it is not working.

I used firebug and found that, the success or error functions are being skipped and goes directly to `return Success;`

Can't seem to find what's the problem with the code.

**Update:**
adding `async: false` fixed the problem

Comment: That's how Ajax works... welcome to async! If it comforts you: It feels like at least three people ask this question *every day*.

Comment: You don't know how to correctly inspect the code. A breakpoint may have been more helpful since AJAX is asynchronous

Comment: Did you put an alert before Success = true

Comment: Doubt anyone's coming back here, but what's better about this "duplicate" is that the words it uses in the title are I think a lot more likely to match the search of someone having this problem.  In the case of the other answer you would have to specifically already understand the answer somewhat to generate a search that would lead you to that page.  Of course, this page leads you to that page, but still.

Comment: Try to use following:                                                                                        
            ```                                                                                                         
           complete: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("Called when Ajax request completes");
            } ```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

change your code to:

```
function ChangePurpose(Vid, PurId) {
    var Success = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CHService.asmx/SavePurpose",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ Vid: Vid, PurpId: PurId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            Success = true;
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Success = false;
        }
    });
    //done after here
    return Success;
}
```

You can only return the values from a `synchronous` function. Otherwise you will have to make a `callback`.

So I just added `async:false,` to your ajax call

**Update:**

jquery ajax calls are asynchronous by default. So success & error functions will be called when the ajax load is complete. But your return statement will be executed just after the ajax call is started.

**A better approach will be:**

```
     // callbackfn is the pointer to any function that needs to be called
     function ChangePurpose(Vid, PurId, callbackfn) {
        var Success = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CHService.asmx/SavePurpose",
            dataType: "text",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Vid: Vid, PurpId: PurId }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                callbackfn(data)
            },
            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                callbackfn("Error getting the data")
            }
        });
     } 

     function Callback(data)
     {
        alert(data);
     }
```

and call the ajax as:

```
 // Callback is the callback-function that needs to be called when asynchronous call is complete
 ChangePurpose(Vid, PurId, Callback);
```

Comment: That... that. worked! Thanks so much. But how can you explain it?

Comment: @Ruchan: Read the question in linked to in my first comment. It explains it and also why using this solution (`async:false`) is not good.

Comment: i understand it(Felix Kling) but what work around would be there? I need to display message there.

Comment: @Felix Kling: you are correct. Updated my answer.
Ruchan: You can use async:false, if you need synchronous calls (in cases like, your code will not continue without the ajax script etc)

Comment: Somebody down-voted me for nothing?

Comment: @Wolf shouldn't the `function Callback(data)` be `function ChangePurpose(data)`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/abimob/348/edit i looked up this... and your update is quite confusing @Wolf

Comment: @Ruchan: What exactly are you having trouble understanding? What callbacks are and how they work?

Comment: @FelixKling I understood what callbacks are, but still cant understand how to define them... Looking up some examples right now...

Comment: @Ruchan: There is an example in this answer and in mine (link). A callback is just a function that is passed to another function. You don't have to define it in any special way. The *other* function just has to expect a callback and call it eventually.

Comment: @Ruchan: did you try the updated code?

Comment: @FelixKling wolf's update is not working. can you make it right?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I just typed the code. Didn't try it. But doesn't seems like having an error.

Comment: It didnt respond.. i looked up in firebug the code got greyed... meaning no breakpoint or something

Comment: Sorry i had some typing mistakes... it is working Correctly now \/ Thanks very much

Comment: thanks a ton @Wolf. It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 11):

Try to encapsulate the ajax call into a function and set the async option to false. Note that this option is deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

```
function foo() {
    var myajax = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CHService.asmx/SavePurpose",
        dataType: "text",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Vid: Vid, PurpId: PurId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false, //add this
    });
    return myajax.responseText;
}
```

You can do this also:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CHService.asmx/SavePurpose",
    dataType: "text",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Vid: Vid, PurpId: PurId }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false, //add this
}).done(function ( data ) {
        Success = true;
}).fail(function ( data ) {
       Success = false;
});
```

You can read more about the [jqXHR jQuery Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: yeah adding async: false worked . thanks