# Jquery success and onComplete not working when sending data

Tags: jquery, postdata

I am trying to send data array in Ajax request and it sends data correctly but **success** and **onComplete** events are not being called. Code below doesn't alert "dd"

```
                    var prodData = {};
                    prodData['product']='316';
                    prodData['qty']='1';                       
                    prodData['isAjax']='1';

                    jQuery.ajax({                           
                        url:'<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>ajax/index/add',                            
                        type:'post',
                        data:prodData,
                        success:function (response) {  
                            alert('dd');
                        }

                    });
```

But code in next section does, difference is only extra parameter data.

```
                    jQuery.ajax({                           
                        url:'<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>ajax/index/add',                            
                        type:'post',
                        success:function (response) {  
                            alert('dd');
                        }

                    });
```

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Check your "error" callback method. It must be throwing some error.

Comment: may be your server is not returning 200 status or may your call is synchronous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475853/jquery-ajax-call-doesnt-call-success-or-error

Comment: Yes @UmairAbid it was returning 302, was problem on controller side.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is data option only takes PlainObject or Strings

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the parameters, you play with them on the server and the response is an error.