# jQuery ajax request going to a different url than expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request to the server in a click event handler. Here's the code:

```
a.ajax("/manage_content/" + b, {
            data: {
                widget_id: d.data("widget-id")
            },
            success: function(e) {
                //some code
            },
            error: function(e, g, f) {
                //troubleshooting code 
                console.log("jqXHR: ", e);
                console.log("textStatus: ", g);
                console.log("errorThrown: ", f)
            }
        })
```

Now, this should go to domain-name/manage_content/whatever-b-is. But, it doesn't. It instead just makes a request to the domain name which comes back with a 200. Neither the success nor the error callbacks are executed. I know that the initial part of this code is executed, it goes into data and everything and then something goes wrong (silently). What could be the reason for this kind of behaviour?

I looked at other SO questions, and there's no redirection in my case. I stay on the same page and only one request goes off in the network panel (which I just described).

Edit: According to the Sources panel's Scope tab, value of b is "enable_widget".

Comment: What's the value of `b`? If `b == ".."` that will cause this result.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it inside the network tab of the chrome devtools?

Comment: @ShridharSharma Yes. This is apparently the only javascript that gets executed.

Comment: @Barmar I can see b = "enable_widget" in the local scope tab.

Comment: Did you step into $.ajax?

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why it would be sending to `/` rather than `/manage_content/enable_widget`

Comment: When you go into the Network tab, what URL does it say it's sending the request to?

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes. It progresses to the data part, and then just exits.

Comment: `a.ajax` is `jQuery.ajax`?

Comment: @Barmar just the domain name. "http://my-site.com/". And yes, a is $ in the codebase.

Comment: Do you use `$.ajaxPrefilter()` to modify AJAX options?

Comment: @Barmar Nope. not using ajaxPrefilter

Comment: How are you executing this code? Is it from a form submit button? Make sure you use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Is the URL /manage_content/enable_widget actually working?  If you go to that URL directly in the browser, what happens?

Comment: @DougF It gets the work done. I get this json in response: {
success: "true",
widget_status: "enabled"
}
I guess the backend code is working fine

Comment: OK, and I know you've said you've searched SO for an answer, but have you tried putting in async:false like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475853/jquery-ajax-call-doesnt-call-success-or-error ?

Comment: @DougF Adding async:false doesn't solve the problem. The difference between this question and mine is that their ajax call was going through, just the success callback wasn't getting executed. In my case, the request is not going to the intended url at all.